# Azure Machine Learning Experiment can't mount blob storage to compute cluster

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Azure ML workspace. I'm having an issue with running ML experiment for segmentation. When I submit a run it will always end with this error:

`UserError: AzureMLCompute job failed. BFSMountError: Unable to mount blob fuse file system Info: Could not mount Azure Blob Container azureml-blobstore-{UID} at workspaceblobstore: Unauthorized. Cannot access the storage account with the given account key. Please verify that the account key is valid. Info: Failed to prepare an environment for the job execution: Job environment preparation failed on 10.0.0.5 with err exit status 1.`

I believe that documentation says that this blob is created automatically for storage of model files.

Storage account in which this blob resides is integrated into VNET. Datastore has `Use workspace managed identity for data preview and profiling in Azure Machine Learning studio` set to yes, access key has been copied from storage account portal page, number of times. I have no idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reaching out to us.

Please check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-workspace-vnet for Azure Machine Learning resources vNet settings.

For this specific error, can you please help to confirm the following settings in your workspace:

1. whether storage account(workspaceblobstore) is within the same vNet with the compute?
2. whether allow access to microsoft service is checked in the storage account(workspaceblobstore)

[image]